# Yielded Pages Stuck in Header in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Getting a weird formatting issue in Rails after adding a header partial.  The hero-unit class inside home.html.erb is being rendered underneath the header tag even though all tags are properly closed.  I'm using the bootstrap cdn to get my classes, and I have almost nothing overriding the defaults.

application.html.erb

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-invserse">
  <%= link_to "Item Database", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <% if signed_in? %>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</header>
```

home.html.erb

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h2>Type a search term</h2>
  <%= form_tag items_path, class: "form-inline", method: "get" do %>
    <div id="search_container" class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search_bar_home", class: "form-control" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, id: "search_btn_home", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

body {
    background: url('/assets/background');  
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    color: white;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
}

i {
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top). There is an explicit red-box warning that states:

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> ```
> body { padding-top: 70px; }
> ```
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

This is because fixed position elements (which are a function of basic HTML, not Bootstrap) by definition float over the top of other elements. There's [a pretty good explanation of fixed, relative, and absolute positioning at CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).